# Generalize Polygons in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, generalization

I would like to use different generalization tools for polygons in QGIS 3.0.
Especially for aggregation, simplifying and smoothing. 
Back using QGIS 2.8 there were the following possibilities:

1. Vector -> Geometrie Tools --> Simplify
2. Using the Toolbox which included the GRASS GIS generalization methods
3. The Generalizer extension --> https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/generalizer/

In Version 3.0 I only found the first option. The second one is merged into v.generalize, am I right?

The third option seems to be not compatible with the 3.0 version.

Have I missed something and is there a good alternative I could use instead of the options above?

Comment: If you type in "general" in the _Processing Toolbox_ for QGIS 3, you should find the `Simplify`, `Smooth` and `v.generalize` tools (the latter of which contains the separate functions which were listed in QGIS 2.x). I don't think there are any generalisation plugins **as of yet** :)